# Rails 4: Get Controller class from Model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any easy way to get Controller class name from Model class?.
Example:

```
Invoice => InvoicesController
```

Tried [tabalize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-tableize) but it returns "invoices"

```
Invoice.to_s.tabalize => "invoices"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = Invoice
s.name.pluralize + 'Controller'
=> "InvoicesController"
```

To get the controller class itself...

```
"InvoicesController".constantize
=> InvoicesController
```